# How to make a div so that it becomes a circle before, after and throughout the transition?

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm making a circle which when hovered results in the enlargement of the whole circle as shown in the code. I have set the `border-radius` to half the width and height of the div (= circle). When I hover over the circle, it enlarges. I have also set the `border-radius` of the resulting structure to half the width and height (i.e. the resulting body is also a circle). But when the cursor is removed and the circle is going back to its original size, the corners become more square like:

> [image]

and then the corners smooth out further and the div becomes a circle when it reaches the starting position as shown below:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: skyblue;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

div:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

However, I want the div to be a circle in the whole process. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the transition your div has a width from **200px** and finishing on **50px** so the calculation of border radius will not fit.

What you need to do is to set a border radius in %. in this case **50%** and you will have the desired result.

p.s you can remove border radius in div:hover css as it doesnt have any effect in your case

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: skyblue;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius: 50%` is a better way to make circles in css

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: skyblue;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: less noisy, more accurate, earlier answer isn't selected as accepted answer.

Comment: Ahh... I refreshed the page when I asked the question and when opened from notifications, I had two answers and didn't even see the time. I accepted the other answer because, although both the answers suggest the same method and are equally correct, it gave me an explanation as to how to resolve the issue and what was it stemming from. But then again, both are equally correct and brilliant.